# Default constructor cannot be referenced error (Visual studios 2019)

Tags: c++

I am getting an error at the bottom of my code when trying to reference my revised subclass, as follows:

> default constructor of 'Revisedcipher' cannot be referenced -- it is a
> deleted function

I'm not entirely sure what that means or how to fix that. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class SubstitutionCipher {
public:
//Define your key which is a permutation of 26 alphabets
string key;

//Constructor to create an instance which initializes the key with the given permutation
SubstitutionCipher(string k) {
    key = k;
}

//function to encode a string
string encode(string data) {
    //initialize encoded data
    string encodedData = data;
    //replace each character in encodedData with the corresponding mapped data in key. We subtract a char with 'A' to get its position
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        encodedData[i] = key.at(data.at(i) - 'A');
    }
    //return the encoded data
    return encodedData;
}

//function to decode a string
string decode(string data) {
    //initialize decoded data
    string decodedData = data;
    //replace each character in decodedData with the corresponding reverse mapped data in key. We add the position with 'A' to get the corresponding char
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        decodedData[i] = key.find(data.at(i)) + 'A';
    }
    //return the decoded data
    return decodedData;
}

};

class Revisedcipher : public SubstitutionCipher
{
public:
void encrypt(string text, int s)
{
    string result = "";

    // traverse text
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        // apply transformation to each character
        // Encrypt Uppercase letters
        if (isupper(text[i]))
            result += char(int(text[i] + s - 65) % 26 + 65);

        // Encrypt Lowercase letters
        else
            result += char(int(text[i] + s - 97) % 26 + 97);
    }

    // Return the resulting string
 //   return result;
    cout << "\n C_Cipher: " << result;
}
};

//main() method to test the implementation
int main() {
    SubstitutionCipher cipher("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA");
    string data = "HJOIEBSOMN";
    string encodedData = cipher.encode(data);

    cout << data << " encoded as " << encodedData << endl;
    string decodedData = cipher.decode(encodedData);
    cout << encodedData << " decoded as " << decodedData;
    Revisedcipher cc;
    cc.encrypt(data, 4);
}
```

Comment: `Revisedcipher cc;` does not pass an argument so it requires a default constructor. You created only `SubstitutionCipher(string k)` so a string is required and the default constructor is deleted.

Comment: could you advise me on how to do so? Im not very familiar with c++ at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have provided a non-default constructor (one with an argument) for your base class, `SubstitutionCipher` but no *default* constructor (i.e. one with no argument), the latter is *implicitly* deleted. Further, as your derived class, `Revisedcipher` provides no constructor, it does not override the deleted base class constructor.

To fix this, you need to *either* define a default constructor for your base class, *or* provide one for the derived class (or both). You can also do this using a default value for the argument.

Here's how to do it for the derived class:

```cpp
class Revisedcipher : public SubstitutionCipher {
public:
    // Call the base class constructor with a given string, or the 'default' if none...
    Revisedcipher(string rk = "[default]") : SubstitutionCipher(rk) {}
    void encrypt(string text, int s)
    {
    //... and so forth
```

Alternatively, you can provide a default `std::string` argument for your base clase constructor:

```cpp
SubstitutionCipher(string k = "[default value]") {
    key = k;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your base type `SubstitutionCipher` has a user defined constructor, which will disable compiler's auto-generation of the default constructor.

This line:

```
SubstitutionCipher(string k) {
    key = k;
}
```

Any type which inherits this must define a constructor which calls `SubstitutionCipher(string)` with some value.

There are three ways around it that I can think of:

1. You can either direct compiler to generate default constructor as it would have otherwise through this line:

   ```
    SubstitutionCipher() = default;
   ```

   but I don't think that's a very good idea since you'll either have to hard-code the key or leave it blank. Neither is a good option.
2. You can add a constructor to `Revisedcipher` which takes a key parameter and passes that along to the base class, like this:

   ```
     Revisedcipher(const string& key) : SubstitutionCipher(key) { }
   ```
3. You may consider adding a default constructor to `Revisedcipher` instead, which passes some hard-coded key to base.

   ```
     Revisedcipher() : SubstitutionCipher("your hard-coded key") { }
   ```

P.S.: There is a fourth way. You can assign a default value to `key` parameter in the base class.

P.P.S.: The fifth way around this would be to get the key from some external source rather than as a constructor argument.